# Mouseless TFS Checkin (w/ Comment) in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

In VS2010, every UI element/command needed to perform a mouseless commented TFS checkin had a keyboard accelerator.

In VS2012, the "Comment" UI element seems not to have a keyboard accelerator. `Alt+V, E, H` still shows the "Pending Changes" pane, and `Alt+I` still performs the "Check In", but I don't see a mouseless way to add a comment to the changeset before committing it, as the "Comment" input seems to have lost its keyboard accelerator.

Starting from the editor, how can I perform a commented, mouseless TFS checkin in VS2012?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `ctr+q`
2. type *check in* then `enter`
3. type comments
4. `alt+I`

That should do it.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 can be repeated to return to the Comments input if you wander off of it while still in the Pending Changes pane. I'd love for someone to provide a faster way to return to the Comments input in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

We actually improved on this in the RTM version or 2012. Once you have that:

To get to the pending changes page: ctrl+0,p

To always get back to the comment box: alt+1

Note, alt+ where n is a number will bring your focus to the different sections of the page throughout all of Team Explorer.

Comment: What is the name of the command that I execute when I use that first shortcut you cited?

Answer (score 1):

My friend, you can go to tool --> option --> shortcut
then search checkin and you will find fs checkin
just assign shortcut like Alt + z 
and then you can check in just by enyer two below  shortcut
1- Alt + z
2- Alt + I